# How do I have different sound output for different apps?

Tags: applications, audio, bluetooth-audio, custom-sounds

Suppose I am connected to my Bluetooth speaker. I want to play my Youtube Music/Music Player on the speaker.

Now, if I turn on Instagram reels, what happens is the Music Player gets paused and the audio output happens through the Bluetooth speaker. What I want is for my Insta sound output should be through my phone's speaker.

**Is there any way by which this can be achieved?**

There can be many more use cases for this but this is just a small example.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Samsung device, this feature is included with [SoundAssistant](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.soundassistant?langCd=en); note that this application isn't usually installed out-of-box.  Other devices may vary based on OEM/model/etc, but if there's no native support you should still be able to find a comparable third party application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work as long as your device is indeed an Android, but do you know what version you're running? Just in case it makes a difference, these are the steps for Android 13 and I believe 11 & 12 as well.

Try these steps first

1. Go to your device Settings
2. Tap on Sound & Notifications, or it might say Sound & Volume, or even Sound & Vibration. Depends on your phone. But as long as it mentions Sound.
3. Scroll down and should hopefully see an option of Separate app sound > Tap to select
4. Tap Turn on now
5. For each input:

   - App - select the app (or Apps) from the list of installed apps shown
   - Audio Device - Select which **different device to use** for your selected app.

It's pretty straightforward after that. Pair and Sync and your Bluetooth should be set up as a separate Device for app sounds. Your system device media player will take care of the Insta reels.

Hope that helps and does the job.

**These steps are for a Samsung phone

Comment: As you have noted, the "Separate app sound" is only available on Samsung devices. Android by default doesn't provide a built-in feature to output audio to separate devices.

Comment: That said, welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange! Please note that [we're a bit different than discussion forums](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, we appreciate everyone's contribution, you might find [How do I write a good answer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) useful for your future contributions :)

Comment: thank you Andrew! appreciate the links and advice. however as an everyday User, retired SAP S/W with no coding, formatting or knowledge I think I'll revert back to only reading and enjoying that part of Stack Exchange. Its indeed a great service platform/communitym